# Plugin QGIS Error "QTextEdit.setPlainText(QString): not enough arguments"

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I try to make `save as` button but I got this error message when I tried to save a file in my directory, (I want to save my file in text format (.txt or .doc))

```
File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\condition\conditiondialog.py", line 80, in saveAs
        self._save( _filename )
    File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\condition\conditiondialog.py", line 68, in _save
        f.write( 'Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText() ) )
    TypeError: QTextEdit.setPlainText(QString): not enough arguments
```

This is the code:

```
Recomen = self.ui.btnRec1
QtCore.QObject.connect(Recomen, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compare1)   
Smpan = self.ui.btnSave
QtCore.QObject.connect(Smpan, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.saveAs)       

def Compare1(self):
    input1 = self.ui.lineInput1.text()
    input2 = self.ui.lineInput2.text()
    compare = ''
    if input1 == input2:
        compare = 'Data dapat digunakam'
    else:
        compare = 'Data tidak cocok'
    self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText(compare)

def _save(self, simpan):        
    f = open( simpan, 'w' )
    f.write( 'Input 1 :' + str(self.ui.lineInput1.text()) ) 
    f.write( 'Input 2 :' + str(self.ui.lineInput2.text()) )
    f.write( 'Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText()) )       
    f.close()
def savefile(self):
    if self.simpan:
          self._save( "%s" % self.simpan )
    else:
          self.saveAs()

def saveAs(self):
    tulis = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
    if tulis !="":
        _filename = "%s" % tulis
        self._save( _filename )
```

Comment: Are you missing part of the code? The first 2 lines seem to be indented too much? Please verify the code is correctly displayed.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i accidentaly tab the first 2 line when copying it from notepad++ but it work fine in my pc (no indentation error) and QGIS can load it, error happen when i try save file to directory (ex C:\Document\practice)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [toPlainText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop) method to get the text from the text-edit:

```
    f.write('Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.toPlainText()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing code, since the error message refers to line 80. But the error 
message also refers to

```
f.write( 'Rekomendasi :' + str(self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText()) ).
```

And according to documentation .setPlainText needs a QString for input.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop